# Advanced `uniq` with "unique part regex"

Tags: regex, linux, shell, awk, uniq

`uniq` is a tool that enables once to filter lines in a file such that only unique lines are shown. `uniq` has some support to specify when two lines are "equivalent", but the options are limited.

I'm looking for a tool/extension on `uniq` that allows one to enter a regex. If the captured group is the same for two lines, then the two lines are considered "equivalent". Only the "first match" is returned for each equivalence class.

**Example**:

`file.dat`:

```
foo!bar!baz
!baz!quix
!bar!foobar
ID!baz!
```

Using `grep -P '(!\w+!)' -o`, one can extract the "unique parts":

```
!bar!
!baz!
!bar!
!baz!
```

This means that the first line is considered to be "equivalent" with the third and the second with the fourth. Thus only the first and the second are printed (the third and fourth are ignored).

Then `uniq '(!\w+!)' < file.dat` should return:

```
foo!bar!baz
!baz!quix
```

Comment: Do you have a better example? Not sure how you'd ever make that regex do what you want without writing something custom, but quite sure there'd be a solution using some standard tools if we can see how your data would look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using `uniq` but using gnu-awk you can get the results you want:

```
awk -v re='![[:alnum:]]+!' 'match($0, re, a) && !(a[0] in p) {p[a[0]]; print}' file
foo!bar!baz
!baz!quix
```

- Passing required regex using a command line variable `-v re=...`
- `match` function matches regex for each line and returns matched text in `[a]`
- Every time `match` succeeds we store matched text in an associative array `p` and print
- Thus effectively getting `uniq` function with `regex` support

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error: `context is match($0, >>>  re, <<<`

Comment: Make sure you're using gnu-awk as written in my answer.

Comment: I'm on Mac OS, maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple Perl script that will do the work:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $re = qr($ARGV[0]);

my %matches;
while(<STDIN>) {
    next if $_ !~ $re;
    print if !$matches{$1};
    $matches{$1} = 1;
}
```

Usage:

```
$ ./uniq.pl '(!\w+!)' < file.dat
foo!bar!baz
!baz!quix
```

Here, I've used `$1` to match on the first extracted group, but you can replace it with `$&` to use the whole pattern match.
This script will filter out lines that don't match the regex, but you can adjust it if you need a different behavior.

Comment: Man, StackOverflow's awesome. Thanks @LucasTrzesniewski :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just `grep` and `sort`

```
DATAFILE=file.dat

for match in $(grep -P '(!\w+!)' -o "$DATAFILE" | sort -u); do 
  grep -m1 "$match" "$DATAFILE";
done
```

Outputs:

```
foo!bar!baz
!baz!quix
```

Comment: Isn't a side effect that the values will get sorted?

Comment: I don't know about "side effect" - it's something that will happen. How big is the input file? If you want something much smarter, the perl solution is perfect.