# Perform uniq only on matching lines while also ignoring some columns

Tags: regex, perl, awk, uniq

Let's say I have an input file that looks like this:

```
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:15 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
```

I could remove all of the duplicate consecutive lines ignoring first 2 columns with `uniq -f2 file.txt` but I'm looking for a way to remove only the duplicates that have `has connected.` in them so the output will look like this:

```
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
```

I suppose this could be done just by matching a fixed string ("has connected.") but I'm also interested in a command that would work with a regex.

I took a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633425/advanced-uniq-with-unique-part-regex) but couldn't modify the commands so they would work with the input I have.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F'>' '!(/has connected/ && seen[$2]++)' file
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-line Perl solution

```
perl -nE 'print unless /has connected/ && @s{/>\s+(.+)/}++' myfile.log
```

#### output

```
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
```

*Note that the use of a* **hash slice** `@s{/>\s+(.+)/}++` *is deliberate. It would normally be an error, but here it serves to put the regex in list context*

---

If you want something cute like [Chris Charley wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37626231/622310) that will report *connected* only if the user was previously disconnected, then it's not sensibly possible in a one-liner. This script will do that for you

If you're unfamiliar with Perl, then to run this on a file you should change `<DATA>` to `<>` and run the program like this

```
$ perl filter.pl myfile.log
```

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %online;

while ( <DATA> ) {

    next unless my ($name, $op) = />\s+(.+)\s+(disconnected|has connected)\./;

    if ( $op eq 'disconnected' ) {
        delete $online{$name};
        print;
    }
    else {
        print unless $online{$name}++;
    }
}

__DATA__
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:15 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:15 > user1 disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
```

#### output

```
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:15 > user1 disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
```

Answer (score 0):

with awk:

```
awk -F">" '!($2 in a) || $2 ~ /disconnected/ {a[$2]=$2; print}' < file.txt
```

check if a value is already present in a array or bypasses if a string has 'disconnected' in it

```
!($2 in a) || $2 ~ /disconnected/
```

output

```
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this perl solution might be what you want. I added some more lines in the data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %seen;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/ > (.+? connected)/) {
        print unless $seen{$1}++;
    }
    else {
        %seen = ();
        print;  
    }   
}

__DATA__
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:15 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:31 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:31 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:34 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:50 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:51 > user2 has connected.
```

This prints

```
2016-06-03 21:00:14 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:22 > foobar disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:29 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:30 > user2 has disconnected.
2016-06-03 21:00:31 > user1 has connected.
2016-06-03 21:00:50 > user2 has connected.
```